# When I insert new faker data in my fixture, I need to update many assertion, have you some tips to fix that?

Tags: python, fixtures, faker

since some time, I use Faker tools ([Python Faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker), [Php Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker), [Ruby Faker](http://faker.rubyforge.org/)...) to generate my fixtures for my tests or my demo datas.

I want to get always the same generated data then I use [random seed feature](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/random.html#random.seed), here is a  very simple example :

```
import unittest
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
fake.seed(4321)

# My model
class Contact(object):
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_basic(self):
        c1 = Contact(fake.first_name(), fake.last_name())
        self.assertEqual(c1.firstname, u'Deonte')
        self.assertEqual(c1.lastname, u'Jaskolski')

        c2 = Contact(fake.first_name(), fake.last_name())
        self.assertEqual(c2.firstname, u'Anika')
        self.assertEqual(c2.lastname, u'Dare')

unittest.main()
```

Ok, all is wonderful.

Next, I work on my project and I need to append a new field to Contact :

```
class Contact(object):
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, city):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.city = city
```

I update my test :

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_basic(self):
        c1 = Contact(fake.first_name(), fake.last_name(), fake.city())
        self.assertEqual(c1.firstname, u'Deonte')
        self.assertEqual(c1.lastname, u'Jaskolski')
        self.assertEqual(c1.city, u'East Freddieside')

        c2 = Contact(fake.first_name(), fake.last_name(), fake.city())
        self.assertEqual(c2.firstname, u'Allison')
        self.assertEqual(c2.lastname, u'Dibbert')
        self.assertEqual(c2.city, u'West Leathabury')
```

If you look "c2.firstname" and "c2.lastname" assertion in first and second test, you can see my pain : When I insert new fake data in the  middle of my fixtures generation, I need to update all of the following assertions.

It's not a problem with small test, but it's very painful multiple tests.

Have you some tips about this issue ?

I have think about use many random generator instances, do you think it's a good direction ?

Comment: I hope by now you have found the solution. I found it always helpful to think in terms of the 3 As: Arrange, Act, Assert. And as @gawel pointed out, you should set the expected value first in each test, so you can compare it to the actual value in the Assert part of the tests.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the data first then create an assertion based on those data. Also I recommend to use namedtuple and a reusable factory.

```
ContactData = namedtuple('Contact', ['first_name', 'last_name', 'city'])
def contactFactory():
   return ContactData(fake.first_name(), fake.last_name(), fake.city())
d1 = contactFactory()
c1 = Contact(*d1) # or Contact(**vars(d1))
assert c1.first_name == d1.first_name
```

Answer (score -2):

This is not a good unit test case because it depends on the behaviour of the Faker library. The outcome of the test case can change if the creators of Faker change their list of names. At the same time, your code might not have changed at all.

A good test case should be self-contained and test a very specific piece of code. For e.g.

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_basic(self):
        c1 = Contact(u'Deonte', u'Jaskolski', u'East Freddieside')
        self.assertEqual(c1.firstname, u'Deonte')
        self.assertEqual(c1.lastname, u'Jaskolski')
        self.assertEqual(c1.city, u'East Freddieside')
```

Again, from a Django perspective, this test case is not necessary. Django code is quite well tested. Writing a test case to check if the model instance has been initialised correctly would be redundant.

Comment: I think you don't understand the goal of Faker. With faker I can write a loop and insert 10000 rows with "real" data. With your method, it's not possible.

Comment: I get that. But I don't understand why you would insert 10000 rows of "random" data and then assert what values were inserted in a test case.